# React-Redux : how to make ReCaptcha a required field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, recaptcha

in my react-redux form, i want to make recaptcha a required field, and disable my navigation bar component until recaptcha response is verified, i found some similar questions with javaScript but i wasn't able to apply them with React, because i am using react-recaptcha plugin :

```
  <div className="form_wrapper">
  <ReCAPTCHA
            sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxx"
            render="explicit"
            onloadCallback={this.callback}
            verifyCallback={this.verifyCallback}
          />
  </div>
  <NavigationBar
     fields={requiredFields}
    // disableNext={this.props} (here where i make conditions to disable)
    />
```

here are my callback and verifyCallback methods:

```
  verifyCallback(response) {
     return response;
 }
 callback() {
console.log('Done !!');
}
```

thank you

i added the code suggested by Hardik Modha, as follows but still having the same issue:

```
 <NavigationBar
     fields={requiredFields}
     disableNext={this.props ... && !this.validateForm()} 
    />

 verifyCallback(response) {
this.setState({
  reCaptchaResponse: response,
});
 }

 validateForm() {
if (!this.state.reCaptchaResponse || this.state.reCaptchaResponse.trim().length === 0) {
  return false;
}
return true;
 }
```

Comment: Are you using redux-form to handle forms?

Comment: no i am not using redux-form, the user is filling the forms and when he click next , there is a simple redirection to the next page. I am not willing for now to verify recaptcha on server side, only in my frontend

Comment: Are you using [react-google-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha) for reCaptcha?

Comment: no i am using react-recaptcha : https://github.com/appleboy/react-recaptcha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var Recaptcha = require('react-recaptcha');

// specifying verify callback function
var verifyCallback = function (response) {
   this.setState({
        reCaptchaResponse: response
    });
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Recaptcha
    sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    render="explicit"
    verifyCallback={verifyCallback}
    onloadCallback={callback}
  />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

You can pass a prop `verifyCallBack` to `react-recaptcha`, in that callback function you can store the response in state or wherever you want. Now, if response is empty you can simply disable the next button or you can put validation when user clicks on validation.

e.g. If you are storing response in state then you can check whether reCaptcha response is empty or not.

```
validateForm() {

    // other field validations....

    if (!this.state.reCaptchaResponse || this.state.reCaptchaResponse.trim().length === 0) {
        return {success: false, message: 'Captcha is required.'};
    }
}
```

**Edit**: For the edited question,
You can also create a state variable say `btnDisabled` and initialize it with true.

```
constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = {btnDisabled: true};
}
```

and `Next` button as

```
<button disabled={this.state.btnDisabled}>Next</button>
```

Now, in your `validateForm` method you can check whether the reCaptcha response is empty or not and based on that you can set the `btnDisabled` variable to true or false.

```
validateForm() {

    // other field validations....

    if (!this.state.reCaptchaResponse || this.state.reCaptchaResponse.trim().length === 0) {
        return {success: false, message: 'Captcha is required.'};
    } else {
        this.setState({
            btnDisabled: false
        });
    }
}
```

**Side Note: You should never rely on client side validations. User can easily bypass client side validations. So, You should implement server side validations, too.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer , is there a possibility to make validateForm return true, and then in my disableNext prop : disableNext = {     this.validateForm() === false}

Comment: Yes, You are right. If your validate form returns false then you disable the `next` button as `<button disabled={!this.validateForm()}>Next</button>`.
But again you should not rely on client side validations.

Comment: no it didn't work unfortunatly, i edited my post following the code you suggested,

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: my Next button is enabled even before captcha filling

Comment: You can set another variable say `btnDisabled` in state and by default initialize with true. So, button will be disabled by default at first. If  `validateForm()` returns true then you can set that variable to false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133287/discussion-between-mettaibi-and-hardik-modha).